# How can you hide modules form all listings without deleting them

Tags: 7, users

I have a growing collection of modules on site.  My module management page and on my feature management page are starting to get cluttered (even with module filter enabled.)  Several of these modules are example modules which are disables and currently only serve to clutter things up.  I would like to hide these modules so that they do not appear in any of my module  lists.  I don't want to delete them (or alter their code if possible.)  Is there a way to temporarily hide a module so it does not appear in any of the module lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this module to Hide.

[Hide Module](https://drupal.org/project/hide_modules)

This will hide the module based on role.

> Hide Modules allows selected modules not being listed at the module administration page except for selected roles.
>
> It enables administrators to safely grant 'administer modules' permission to other roles and keeping at the same time some modules out of the list to avoid untrusted users enabling or disabling them.

Comment: I should have guessed... there is a module for that